# Firebase auth dependency missing error in Huawei device (without google play service) for Unity

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

**Problem** We are getting an exception with Huawei device for Unity application - initializationException: Firebase modules failed to initialize: auth (missing dependency)

**What we did**

As mentioned in firebase doc [Link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/android-play-services) that latest firebase auth version will work on devices without google play services. We have updated firebase dependencies versions to the latest. But we are having issues in our unity application. As there is no update yet for Unity with latest firebase version. So We did edited AuthDependencies.xml ,AppDependencies.xml, AnalyticsDependencies.xml for latest firebase auth , analytics versions.

UNITY Version - 2019.4.10f1 Unity Firebase Version - 6.16.1

**mainTemplate.gradle**

```
([rootProject] + (rootProject.subprojects as List)).each { project ->
    project.repositories {
        def unityProjectPath = $/file:///**DIR_UNITYPROJECT**/$.replace("\\", "/")
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        maven {
            url (unityProjectPath + "/Assets/GeneratedLocalRepo/Firebase/m2repository") // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AnalyticsDependencies.xml:18, Assets/Firebase/Editor/AppDependencies.xml:22, Assets/Firebase/Editor/AuthDependencies.xml:20
        }
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
// Android Resolver Repos End
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
**APPLY_PLUGINS**

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
// Android Resolver Dependencies Start
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.5.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AppDependencies.xml:17
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AuthDependencies.xml:15
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-unity:6.16.1' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AnalyticsDependencies.xml:18
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-app-unity:6.16.1' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AppDependencies.xml:22
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:20.0.1' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AuthDependencies.xml:13
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-unity:6.16.1' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AuthDependencies.xml:20
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.4.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AppDependencies.xml:13
// Android Resolver Dependencies End
**DEPS**}



// Android Resolver Exclusions Start
android {
  packagingOptions {
      exclude ('/lib/armeabi/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/mips/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/mips64/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/x86/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/x86_64/*' + '*')
  }
}

// Android Resolver Exclusions End
android {
    compileSdkVersion **APIVERSION**
    buildToolsVersion '**BUILDTOOLS**'

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion **MINSDKVERSION**
        targetSdkVersion **TARGETSDKVERSION**
        ndk {
            abiFilters **ABIFILTERS**
        }
        versionCode **VERSIONCODE**
        versionName '**VERSIONNAME**'
        consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-unity.txt'**USER_PROGUARD**
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    aaptOptions {
        ignoreAssetsPattern = "!.svn:!.git:!.ds_store:!*.scc:.*:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~"
    }**PACKAGING_OPTIONS**
}**REPOSITORIES****SOURCE_BUILD_SETUP**
**EXTERNAL_SOURCES**
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, even though the Firebase Android SDK works without Google Play Services (GPS) the SDK built for Unity does not.

Specifically, in the earlier days of Firebase, it didn't function without GPS. Since Unity doesn't really have a main entry point and Firebase is mostly lazily initialized via singletons, at the root of the chain (creating the Firebase App), the presence of GPS is checked before making the default app instance.

You have a few options at this point:

1. Unity does have some relatively robust JNI support. You *can* bind to the Android SDK directly from Unity if you're comfortable working in native Android.
2. The Firebase team is aware of this shortcoming. You can subscribe to [this issue](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/223) to get notified of any advancements, but there isn't an ETA.
3. You can always reach out to [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact) directly.